# Is Continuous Localization Enough to Explain the Quantum/Classical Divide?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence

Regardless to whether the mechanism is spreading entanglement (many worlds interpretation) or decoherence, it seems to me that if a particle is continuously localized (for example, as described in [this paper by Max Tegmark](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9310032)) then it's behavior will be classical. This would be the case whether the motion of the particle is Brownian/stochastic or well described by a smooth trajectory. This information doesn't seem to have percolated down to undergraduate textbooks, though, so I have to assume that there's a problem I'm missing. Does anyone know what that problem is?

Comment: I am so far out of my depth on this subject, I need a lifejacket, but it seems to me that, from comments by people who know the field, that decoherence is only accepted up to a certain level, or for certain specific situations, otherwise its an obvious route, so, I would appreciate any answers to sort this out for me. I am not sure its the same question Sean is asking, apologies if it is.